# In Atlassian Bamboo, is there any way to get the latest build status as an image?

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

Is there a way to get the latest build status of a Bamboo plan in a way that can be included in an external page (for example in a GitHub README.md file).

The latest build status is available as XML from http://my.bamboo.server.url/rest/api/latest/result/PLAN-NAME/latest

An ideal solution would be an image URL, similar to the [Travis CI Status Images](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/status-images/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is any way to do this out of the box, but Atlassian Labs offers a free plugin: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.atlassian-bamboo-plugin-build-status-image